# Breaking the support of a random variable using identity functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have this doubt abuot the following equivalence.
Let X a real valued-random variable and let $a\in\mathbb{R}$, is it true that

$$X=X\mathbb{1}_{\{X\leq a\}}+X\mathbb{1}_{\{X> a\}}?$$

I found that if X takes values in a countable set S of outcomes it is ture that

$$X=\sum_{x\in S}x\mathbb{1}_{\{X=x\}}$$

but I do not understand if the countability is required just to have a countable number of summands or if it is actually an foundamental property of the state space.

Comment: Why don't you just evaluate both sides at an arbitrary $\omega\in \Omega$ and see what happens? (Here, $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true, and we don't need to argue from the countable case. We know that $X$ will either take on a value $\leq a$ or a value $> a$, and never both. In the first case, the first term in the sum will have the value of $X$, and the second term in the sum will have the value of $0$; in the second case, the first term in the sum will have the value of $0$, and the second term in the sum will have the value of $X$. Either way, they will sum to the value of $X$.